# link after two autoComplete input jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete, hyperlink, combinations

I am making online Kyoto bus route. So I have start and end autoComplete in my code. My goal is to write code that recognizes combination of major stops and link to(or play) a new html file.

Here is my HTML code.
.......

```
<body>
<div id = "buttons">
<h1> Kyoto Bus Map</h1>
<label for="autocomplete">start </label>
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="where is your closest bus station?" />

<label for="autocomplete1">end</label> 
<input id="autocomplete1" placeholder="where would you like to go?" /> 
</div>

<script>
var source = [ {label: "kyoto Station"},
               {label: "Gion"},
               {label: "Kyoto Tower"}]; /*I also want my start input to wait until end input is filled.*/

var source1 = [ {value: "kyoto.html", label: "kyoto Station"},
           {value: "gion.html", label: "Gion"},
           {value: "tower.html", label: "Kyoto Tower"}];



$(document).ready(function() {
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
});
});


$(document).ready(function() {
$("input#autocomplete1").autocomplete({
    source: source1,
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
});
});

</script>
</body>
........
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is.

Comment: okay. I need to code to work from place a to b, c, d, e, etc, from b to a, c, d, e etc from c to a, b, d, e etc, from d to a, b, c, e etc.I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to hire a programmer. Or break this task down to the specific problem you're having.

Comment: I was able to code from a to b, c, d, but from b to a, c, d and other combination doesn't work. awwwWWWWW...!